# AltStore Can't be installed

Tags: ios, install

I installed AltStore once successfully, a few days later, all my installed apps and AltStore itself prompts an error message upon launching: "AltStore" is no longer available. Trying to install from the AltServer, it fails. I used the main Apple ID from the old altserver installation and a new apple id
[image]